# Check column names in R and create a dummy column

Tags: r

I have written a function to check if there exists a column in dataframe. If there is no column then create a dummy column

```
add_Column <- function(df, col_name){
  if("col_name" %in% colnames(df)) {
    NULL
  } else{
    df$col_name <- ""
  }
}
```

So when I check below,

```
add_Column(iris, "new")
```

Expected output

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  new
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: You need to return the df in your function at the end.

Comment: Assuming your question is “why doesn’t my code work?”, Don’t put `col_name` in quotes in your `if` statement and return the modified df.

Comment: I tried both suggestions. Did not work

Comment: Also in your else statement use `df[col_name]=""`.

Answer (score 1):

First, add `return` and use `[]` to assign the "new" column name like this:

```r
add_Column <- function(df, col_name){
  if("col_name" %in% colnames(df)) {
    NULL
  } else{
    df[col_name] <- ""
  }
  return(df)
}

add_Column(head(iris), "new")
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa    
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a way to not include ````return(df)```` because only when I call, iris, it should return the final data?

Comment: Can we achieve this without ````return(df)````